# Recurrence relation in the Gambler's Ruin problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

The author of my textbook gives the problem:

> A gambler repeatedly bets \$1 that a coin will come up heads when
> tossed. Each time the coin comes up heads, the gambler wins \$1; each
> time it comes up tails, he loses \$1. Let $P_n$ be the probability
> that the gambler is ruined if he begins playing with \$ $n$, then
>
> $P_{k-1}=\frac{1}{2}P_{k}+\frac12P_{k-2}$
>
> This follows from the fact that if the gambler has \$$(k − 1)$, then he
> has an equal chance of winning \$1 or losing \$1, and if he wins \$1,
> then his chance of being ruined is $P_k$ , whereas if he loses \$1, then
> his chance of being ruined is $P_{k−2}$.)

I fail to understand this equation. It's not recurrence relation - current term depends on one ahead. Also why does the author multiply the probabilities by $\frac12$? This problem is given as an example in the Expected Value section. How does it relate to Expected Value?

Later the author transforms that equation to $P_k=2P_{k-1}-P_{k-2}$ which doesn't make sense to me (not the algebra but the relation between the terms itself - why current term depends on 2 $P_{k-1}$ and 1 $P_{k-2}$) too since it's based on the reasoning for the original one.

Comment: "It's not recurrence relation - current term depends on one ahead." -- You could always just swap $P_k$ and $P_{k-1}$ by subtracting their terms from each side (though why one would present it like that is beyond me).

Comment: The index $k$ does not indicate time; it indicates an amount of holdings.  The recurrence basically says that if you currently have (say) three dollars, your probability of eventually going bust is equal to the average of the probability of eventually going bust if you have four dollars, and the probability of eventually going bust if you have two dollars (because the coin is fair, and those are the two equally probable next states).  It might have been a small bit clearer if it had been written as $P_k = \frac12 P_{k+1} + \frac12 P_{k-1}$.

Comment: As for the last equation, it's simply a straightforward algebraic manipulation of the earlier one.

Comment: There isn't really any direct "natural" interpretation of the last equation; in other words, it really only comes from algebraic manipulation.  The purpose of this manipulation is to produce a recurrence that is more amenable to the usual ways to solve such recurrences (i.e., derive a characteristic equation, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

For the solution of the difference equation it's better to write $1 = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}$ because that is the term of $P_{k-1}$ in the first equation. Then construct difference from each two consecutive terms, obtain the boundary term and then sum on both sides using telescoping summation.

Keep in mind each term/state is a function of $n$, starting fortune, hence $P_n$ is a limiting probability, i.e probability that the gambler will go bankrupt eventually.